# $\int_1^2(3x^2-4x)\ln xdx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_1^2(3x^2-4x)\ln xdx$$
become $$\int_1^23x^2\ln xdx - \int_1^24x\ln xdx$$

using integration by parts :
$$ \int udv = uv - \int v du$$
$$ u = \ln , dv = 3x^2 dx \text{ and } dv = 4x dx$$
$$\ln x. x^3 - x^2 |_1^2 - \ln x.2x^2 - 2x|_1^2$$
but i dont know how to continue.

Answer (score 3):

I would do by parts straight up, without separation: $dv = (3x^2-4x)dx \implies v = x^3-2x^2$ and $u = \ln x \implies du = dx/x$. Thus,
$$
\int\left(3x^2-4x\right)\ln xdx
 = \int udv = uv - \int vdu
 = \left(x^3-2x^2\right) \ln x - \int \frac{x^3-2x^2}{x} dx
$$
and the integral on the RHS simplifies to $\int \left(x^2-2x\right)dx$.

Comment: Nice solution, good one!

Comment: @SarGe thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{2}x^{\mu}\,\dd x & = {2^{\mu + 1} - 1 \over \mu + 1}
\\[2mm]
\int_{1}^{2}x^{\mu}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
{2^{\mu + 1}\ln\pars{2} \over \mu + 1} -
{2^{\mu + 1} - 1 \over \pars{\mu + 1}^{2}}
\\[2mm]
\int_{1}^{2}x^{2}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
{8\ln\pars{2} \over 3} - {7 \over 9}
\\[2mm]
\int_{1}^{2}x\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
2\ln\pars{2} - {3 \over 4}
\\[2mm]
\int_{1}^{2}\pars{3x^{2} - 4x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x & =
3\bracks{{8\ln\pars{2} \over 3} - {7 \over 9}} -
4\bracks{2\ln\pars{2} - {3 \over 4}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{2 \over 3} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

By IBP $$=\ln(x) \int(3x^2-4x) dx -\int\left(\frac{1}{x}\int(3x^2-4x)dx \right)dx\\= \ln(x)(x^3-2x^2) -\int\frac{x^3-2x^2}{x}dx $$ Now its should be easy to do.